# exporting data to excel using java - no rows created

Tags: java, excel

I need help in exporting data to an excel file.

The cells for row 12 is working fine but the cells for rowItems don't display anything at all.

The codes should export a list of items and its attributes from the database.

```
    Row row12 = sheet.createRow(11);
    Cell c12[] = new Cell[maxCols];

    for(int i = 0; i <c12.length; i++){
        c12[i] = row12.createCell(i);
        c12[i].setCellStyle(tableHeader2Bottom);
    }

    c12[0].setCellValue("1");
    c12[1].setCellValue("2");
    c12[2].setCellValue("3");
    c12[3].setCellValue("");
    c12[4].setCellValue("4");
    c12[5].setCellValue("5");
    c12[6].setCellValue("6");
    c12[7].setCellValue("7");
    c12[8].setCellValue("8");
    c12[9].setCellValue("9");
    c12[10].setCellValue("10");
    c12[11].setCellValue("11");
    c12[12].setCellValue("13");
    c12[13].setCellValue("14");
    c12[14].setCellValue("15");
    c12[15].setCellValue("16");

    Row rowItems[] = new Row[items.size()];
    Cell cItems[][] = new Cell[items.size()][maxCols];
    int startRow = 11;
    int endRow = 0;
    if(items.size() == 0){
        endRow = startRow;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
        rowItems[i] = sheet.createRow(i+startRow);
        for(int j = 0; j < cItems[i].length; j++){
            cItems[i][j] = rowItems[i].createCell(j);
            cItems[i][j].setCellStyle(borderedCell);
        }
        cItems[i][0].setCellValue(items.get(i).getName());
        cItems[i][1].setCellValue(1);
        cItems[i][2].setCellValue(items.get(i).getUnitCost());
        cItems[i][3].setCellValue(items.get(i).getUnitCost());
        cItems[i][4].setCellValue(items.get(i).getClassNumber());
        cItems[i][5].setCellValue(items.get(i).getPropertyNumber());
        cItems[i][6].setCellValue(items.get(i).getDateAcquired());
        cItems[i][7].setCellValue("");
        cItems[i][8].setCellValue("");
        cItems[i][9].setCellValue("");
        cItems[i][10].setCellValue("");
        cItems[i][11].setCellValue("");
        cItems[i][12].setCellValue("");
        cItems[i][13].setCellValue("");
        cItems[i][14].setCellValue("");
        cItems[i][15].setCellValue("");
        endRow = (i+startRow);
    }
```

[screenshot of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUhGD.jpg)

cItems[0][0] = A13, cItems[0][1 ] = B13, . . .

The loop should get each item in the database and display it starting from row 13.

By the way, I'm using Apache POI. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Use System.out.println to debug. Print out item.get(i).

Comment: Can you shortly describe what your Excel-Export shall look like, what cell content and format it will have etc.?

Comment: @Lepidopteron I uploaded a screenshot of the excel file. I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing.

May be you should call sheet.addRow(row12) in the end.
The same is with columns row12.addColumn(column).
And in the end sheet.close().

All of these are just guessings, I might be completely wrong ;).

If you tell me what excel lib you are using, then I might be more specific :)